# Installing mitmproxy on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

Tags: java, windows, https, man-in-the-middle

I've been using [`Fiddler`](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to modify a `HTTPS` response sent by the server which has been initiated by a `POST` request of the client which worked fine.

Using `Java` on `Windows` I want to implement this same man-in-the-middle attack so I'm looking for code which can handle system wide `HTTPS` traffic. Importing a certificate into the system's truststore is also necessary but I'm struggling with starting the actual `Java` code. [`mitmproxy`](https://mitmproxy.org/) for instance has a `Windows` installer but it does not ship the `mitmproxy` executable [so it cannot be used](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-installation/#windows). Also using `WSL` I get the following `Python` exception:

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install mitmproxy
[sudo] password for ubuntu:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mitmproxy is already the newest version (2.0.2-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 106 not upgraded.
root@mypc:~$ mitmproxy --port 1080
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 574, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 892, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 783, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (urwid 2.0.1 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('urwid<1.4,>=1.3.1'), {'mitmproxy'})

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/mitmproxy", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3088, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3072, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3101, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 576, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 589, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 778, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'urwid<1.4,>=1.3.1' distribution was not found and is required by mitmproxy
```

<strike>[`LittleProxy-mitm`](https://github.com/ganskef/LittleProxy-mitm)'s maven dependency causes a [`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/util/Encodable`](https://github.com/ganskef/LittleProxy-mitm/issues/34)</strike>.

How can I fix these problems or what else can I use to capture and modify any system-wide `HTTPS` traffic using `Java` programming? It only needs to work on `Windows`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`pip3` installation guide](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-installation/#installation-on-linux-via-pip3) worked:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip && sudo pip3 install -U pip && sudo pip3 install mitmproxy
```

Note: This command applies to `Ubuntu`.

Comment: should we be using pip3 as root?

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu package for mitmproxy hasn't been maintained.
You have 3 options:

You can install it from pip as BullyWiiPlaza explained.

You can get the compiled binaries for linux from https://mitmproxy.org/.

Or you can download the source from github and run it that way.